# Trying to pass a Map to my AsyncTask But I get a: Type safety: A generic array of Map<Date,String> is created for a varargs parameter

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, treemap

[image]

I am doing some DB operation, using Loader, populating a HashMap and then filling  a TreeMap with this HashMap for Sorting puropse, however when I try to pass this TreeMap to my AsyncTask like:

```
Sorted = new TreeMap<Date,String>(BD); 
new MagicCall().execute(Sorted);
```

But the compiler is giving me a warning: Type safety: A generic array of Map is created for a varargs parameter

This is my AsyncTask Declaration:

```
private class MagicCall extends AsyncTask<Map<Date,String>, String, String>
```

Any Heading?

Comment: Java does not like generics in varargs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257883/warning-for-generic-varargs - if you don't like that warning wrap that `TreeMap<X, Y>` into a class without generics.

Comment: Will it cost me anything if I suppress it?

Comment: Besides 1 line of code and the possibility to violate typesafety (you should be able to pass any type of `Map` in there) no.

Comment: Thanks, then I need not bang my head against the wall. I will suppress it!

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem with a workaround.
You can declare your task as follows:

```
private class MagicCall extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

  // member
  private Map<Date,String> arg = null;

  // constructor
  public MagicCall(final Map<Date,String> arg) {
    this.arg  = arg;
  }  

  ...

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(final Void... args) {
     // do stuff on this.arg instead of args
     ...
  }
...
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```
new MagicCall(Sorted).execute();
```

This way you pass the task parameters through the constructor and not via the execute() method.